# Google map react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, google-map-react

```js
 {!loading ? (
        <GoogleMapReact
          defaultZoom={isEqual(latLong, USLatLong) ? 4 : 18}
          defaultCenter={latLong.lat && latLong.lng ? latLong : USLatLong}
          bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: process.env.REACT_APP_GMP_API_KEY }}
          yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals
          onGoogleApiLoaded={handleApiLoaded}
          hoverDistance={20}
          onTilesLoaded={() => setLoading(false)}
        />
      ) : (
        <Loader />)}
```

I have one state variable loading. If it is true then I want to show Loader.
If its false then I want to show Google map.

Now problem is that, In google-map-react how can I set the variable after map loading is completed.

```js
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
```

Comment: Can you show us handleApiLoaded?

Comment: const handleApiLoaded: (maps: { map: any; maps: any; ref: Element | null }) => void = async ({ map, maps }) => {
    setGoogleAPI({ map, maps });
  };

Comment: So, onTilesLoaded={() => setLoading(false)} is not changing the state?

Answer (score 0):

My code looks like this.

I defined `const [mapApiLoaded, setMapApiLoaded] = React.useState(false);` , similar to your `loading`  state variable.

Notice below I have an attribute `onGoogleApiLoaded={({ map, maps }) => apiHasLoaded(map, maps)}`. `apiHasLoaded` is the where I set the variable after map loading.

```js
      <GoogleMapReact
        center={center}
        zoom={zoom}
        draggable={draggable}
        onChange={onChange}
        onChildMouseDown={onMarkerInteraction}
        onChildMouseUp={onMarkerInteractionMouseUp}
        onChildMouseMove={onMarkerInteraction}
        onChildClick={onStoreMarkerClick}
        onClick={onClick}
        bootstrapURLKeys={{
          key: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY!,
          libraries: ["places", "geometry"],
        }}
        yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals
        onGoogleApiLoaded={({ map, maps }) => apiHasLoaded(map, maps)}
      >
```

And my apiHasLoaded function is defined like this:

```
  const apiHasLoaded = (map: any, maps: any) => {
    console.log("apiHasLoaded");
    setMapApiLoaded(true);
    setMapInstance(map);
    setMapApi(maps);
    generateAddress();
  };
```